# Sorting data into Columns based on starting value - Microsoft Excel

Tags: excel, sorting

## **Overview**

I'm trying to sort data returned from a PERL query in Excel. The data came in a jumbled mess.

## Issue:

Because it came in a jumbled mess, there is data that I want in one column that is in another because I used the Text to Column command.

## Example:

```
| ID | Category                                                       | Sub-Category                         | Name                              | SKU      | Price    | Woven in                           | History                                                                                                                                                                                                             | Artist                      |
|----|----------------------------------------------------------------|--------------------------------------|-----------------------------------|----------|----------|------------------------------------|---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|-----------------------------|
| 1  | Belgian Tapestries,   European Tapestries, Flanders Tapestries | Masters of Fine Art,Tapestries       | 3 Ages - Klimt                    | EWA-8319 | $609.00  | Artist: Zanobi Strozzi             |  History : Wall art sample text here                                                                                                                                                                                                                    | Woven In : Woven in Belgium |
| 2  | Floral & Still   Life Tapestries                               | Wine & Feast Still   Life Tapestries | A Date to Remember   Wall Hanging | EWA-1531 | $249.00  |  Woven In : Woven in North America |  History : This wall art still life tapestry   depicts a wonderful feast. |                             |
```

## Fixed dataset:

```
| ID | Category                                                       | Sub-Category                         | Name                              | SKU      | Price    | Woven in                           | History                                                                                                                                                                                                             | Artist               |
|----|----------------------------------------------------------------|--------------------------------------|-----------------------------------|----------|----------|------------------------------------|---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|----------------------|
| 1  | Belgian Tapestries,   European Tapestries, Flanders Tapestries | Masters of Fine Art,Tapestries       | 3 Ages - Klimt                    | EWA-8319 | $609.00  |  Woven In : Woven in Belgium       | History : Wall art sample text here                                                                                                                                                                                 | Artist: Gustav Klimt |
| 2  | Floral & Still   Life Tapestries                               | Wine & Feast Still   Life Tapestries | A Date to Remember   Wall Hanging | EWA-1531 | $249.00  |  Woven In : Woven in North America |  History : This wall art still life tapestry   depicts a wonderful feast.|                      |
```

## Question:

Is there a way to sort the data in a column solely based on the starting Value?

Comment: Over 1000 total, not really effective to do it by hand. Don't think that sorting by Column would either, because of it simply being too jumbled.

Comment: @pnuts There's no more rows being added if that's what you mean.